# Getting libcurl to produce CRLF in email using const char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, libcurl

Using C++, Windows 10, VS 2019, Curl libcurl

I am trying to fill a const char array in order to send an email using libcurl.

The libcurl example defines the char array this way outside of the main()

```
static const char inline_html[] =
"<html><body>\r\n"
"<p>HTML_Body</p>"
"<br />\r\n"
"</body></html>\r\n";
```

However, I have converted the main() in their example code to accept parameters so that I can pass the From, To, CC. Subject, and Body. So at the top of main() I have this:

```
std::string strBody = argv[5];
```

Since the inline_html[] is const I tried to create another array on the fly inside of main() like this

```
char* inline_array = new char[strBody.length() + 1];
```

and then fill it with from the passed parameter strBody.  If I look for char(10) or char(13) in the strBody, they are there but they do not get put into the inline_array[] as anything if I just do this (or at least they do not react as CRLF in the resulting email)

```
for (int i = 0; i < strBody.length(); i++) {
  inline_array[i] = strBody[i];
}
```

The resulting email will just be a run-on block of text with none of the original line feeds that were in the original string.

If I look for the char(10) and (13)s and substitute an escaped character like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < strBody.length(); i++) {
    if (strBody[i] == char(10)) {
        inline_array[i] = '\n'; //  '\x10';
    }
    else if (strBody[i] == char(13)) {
        inline_array[i] = '\x13';  // '\r';
    }
    else {
        inline_array[i] = strBody[i];
    }
}
```

I just get "\r\n" in the final email sent and not the desired CRLF.

I do know that separately I can put the escaped CRLR into a char inline_html2Chr[230] like this

```
inline_html2Chr[i] = '\n';
```

I have done it in debug mode and am able to see that html2Chr[i] == '\n', for instance.

But when I pass this to the libcurl function to send the email like this

```
curl_mime_data(part, inline_html2Chr, CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
```

I still end up with a run-on block of text with only the "\r\n" embedded.

Even if I modify the original inline_html[] in the example code outside of main() to put CRLF in the body like this

```
static const char inline_html[] =
"<html><body>\r\n"
"<p>LineOne\r\nLineTwo</p>"
"<br />\r\n"
"</body></html>\r\n";
```

I get "LineOne LineTwo" as the body with no line break but also no "\r\n" in the body.

Does anyone have a suggestion of what else I can try?  I am just going around in circles and can't even remember all of the variations I have tried.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Ed

Comment: HTML formatting relies on tags like [<br>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) for line break or [<p>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) for paragraph, you probably want these.

Comment: Are you familiar with `std::string`'s method called `c_str()`? You'll be pleasantly surprised to know what it returns.

Comment: And you can just compose html body entirely with `std::string strBody = ...`  and pass `strBody.c_str()` to libcurl where it requries `const char *`

Comment: Jeeeze, this is embarrassing when the answer is so obvious.  I haven't had time to test to make sure but this is the html part of the email and #dewaffled is correct.  CRLF does not play a part in HTML it is <br> as he said.  I had used the c_str() but that wasn't working and I see now it is not so much that c_str() wasn't working but that I needed to substitute <br> instead of \n and \r.  I will post a final answer once I run the actual code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So obvious when you you think in terms of "HTML" and not in terms of string and char.  @dewaffled was correct, `\n` and `\r` are not part of the HTML lexicon.  It has to be `<br>` or `<p>`.

Comment: I see the angle brackets did not get into the answer but the "or" above is supposed to be <br> or <p>